# WCF - TargetInvocationException was unhandled

Tags: wcf, synchronization, smartclient

I'm trying to create WCF to sync my  mobile device with my server. When i try to click sync button it throws TargetInvocationException. Below is the Sync() method.

Code

```
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
            CustomerProxy.CustomerCacheSyncService svcProxy = new CustomerProxy.CustomerCacheSyncService();
            Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ServerSyncProviderProxy syncProxy =
                new Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.ServerSyncProviderProxy(svcProxy);

            // Call SyncAgent.Synchronize() to initiate the synchronization process.
            // Synchronization only updates the local database, not your project's data source.
            CustomerCacheSyncAgent syncAgent = new CustomerCacheSyncAgent();
            syncAgent.RemoteProvider = syncProxy;
             /*throws error below code*/
            Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SyncStatistics syncStats = syncAgent.Synchronize();

            // TODO: Reload your project data source from the local database (for example, call the TableAdapter.Fill method).
            customer_ConfirmationTableAdapter.Fill(testHHDataSet.Customer_Confirmation);

            // Show synchronization statistics
            MessageBox.Show("Changes downloaded: " + syncStats.TotalChangesDownloaded.ToString()
                + "\r\nChanges Uploaded: " + syncStats.TotalChangesUploaded.ToString());

            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message and at which line does it occur? And what have you tried? Put the error message in your favourite search engine and show what solutions you have found but do not work.

Comment: Error : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException was unhandled
  Message="TargetInvocationException" / InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message="Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: I said: _"Put the error message in your favourite search engine and show what solutions you have found but do not work."_, not _"dump the error here"_. The error _"Unable to connect to the remote server"_ has 615.000 hits on Google, there's bound to be something useful there. Have you checked the firewall, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've recreated the Web Service again and it works now. The problem was the mobile device couldnt find my local webservice. Thanks.